# How to resolve 'Connection closed before full header was received' error with CachedNetworkImage widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the CachedNetworkImage widget in my Flutter app to display images from a network source. However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm receiving the error message "Connection closed before full header was received" when trying to load some images. Here's the code I'm using:

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: this.source!,
  height: height,
  width: width,
  fit: this.fit,
  maxHeightDiskCache: 400,
  maxWidthDiskCache: 400,
  memCacheHeight: 400,
  memCacheWidth: 400,
  errorWidget: (context, error, _) => Center(
    child: Icon(
      Icons.error,
      color: ColorConstants.dangerColor,
    )
  ),
)
```

I have verified that the image URLs are correct and accessible when tested in a web browser. However, the error occurs intermittently for certain images. I've also ensured a stable internet connection and checked my firewall settings.

Could anyone please provide insights into why this error might occur and how to resolve it? Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are those links http or https?

Comment: Those links use the https